# Create custom scroll event function and then reverse on scroll back up?

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, scroll, parallax

I need to trigger an event when I scroll a certain distance down the page and then reverse the event when I scroll back up past the original scroll event.

Here's what I've currently tried. This triggers the event when I scroll down a distance. I need to set the progress bar to 10 when I scroll back up.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollY = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollY > 4200) $(this).trigger("first-guy");
    if (scrollY > 1600) $(this).trigger("second-guy");
    if (scrollY > 2200) $(this).trigger("third-guy");
    if (scrollY > 3000) $(this).trigger("fourth-guy");
})

//first guy
.on("first-guy", function() {
    $('progress').animate({
        value: 20
    }, 200);
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply add another case for when `scrollY` is less than the trigger point. So something similar to this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollY = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollY > 200) $(this).trigger("first-guy");
    if (scrollY < 200) $(this).trigger("before-first-guy"); // LESS THAN
})
//first guy
.on("first-guy", function() {
    $('progress').animate({
        value: 20
    }, 200);
 })
//before first guy
.on("before-first-guy", function() {
    $('progress').animate({
        value: 0
    }, 200);
 })
```

Here a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqtmr/1/)**.

Depending on what exactly you are trying to do, you might want to structure it differently or even add variables to check for certain values/events.

Comment: Thanks. This does work. The only problem really is that it seems to be a bit slow. If I have .animate() speed set to anything less than 25 it seems to lag (for more than the 200 milliseconds it's set for) and ruins the effect I'm going for. Any thoughts on how to optimize it?

Comment: Try clearing the animation queue with `.stop()`... so like this: `$('progress').stop(true,true).animate(...)`. See if that removes the delay.

Comment: Awesome! The single .stop().animate() worked great and had the exact effect I needed. I've never used stop before so I'll have to explore stop(true, true) but that seems to stop the animation from happening at all. Thank you.